# Using <div class="something"> inside a jQuery replaceWith() function

Tags: jquery, quotes, double-quotes

I am working on a PHP document which has jQuery code in it. I am using a replaceWith() functions to strip outer divs and replace with span. it seems I can only replace it with `<span>` and not `<span class="something">`

Why is that?

**Edit**: Here is an example of the code:

Thanks Dave, but I actually use the second option in your code above, here is what I am trying to do:

```
$response[] = "jQuery('#myID').replaceWith('<span>'+jQuery('#myID').html()+'</span>');";
```

The above code works. Basically, I have an `<a>` element I want to replace with a `<span>` element and change the class on an ajax response.

Now, if I add classes to any of the spans above:, like this:

```
$response[] = "jQuery('#myID').replaceWith('<span class"something">'+jQuery('#myID').html()+'</span>');";
```

the code breaks, is it because of the outer double-quotes on the jQuery statement?

**Edit**

So it turned out to be an issue with my `<a>` element I was trying to replace, in addition to escaping the double-quotes around the class :). Thanks for the extremely prompt help. I am registering to give credit where credit is due :)

```
$response[] = "jQuery('#myID').replaceWith('<span class=\"something\">'+jQuery('#myID').html()+'</span>');";
```

Comment: Could you please show an example of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the biggest change there is the addition of quotes, double check that the class attribute isn't leaving an unterminated string open:

```
// Broken:                 
$("div").replaceWith("<span class="something">");

// Fixed:
$('div').replaceWith('<span class="something">');
```

Comment: It is the biggest thing there. (+1)

Comment: Thanks Dave, part of the issue did turn out to be unterminated strings :)
I can't vote yet, but will do once I can

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of readability, and to avoid confusing yourself like this, consider using this syntax for jQuery DOM insertion instead:

```
var myDiv = jQuery('#myID');
$('<span></span>').html(myDiv.html()).addClass('something').replaceAll(myDiv);
```

Oh, and if you look carefully at the way your code is highlighted in the question above, you can already see what you're doing wrong ;)

Comment: Thanks Yi, I am sure your above code would work (did not try it) however, I am modifying someone else's work and did not want to break consistency

and your note on highlighted code helped ;)